# How to check what user is trying to access a file?

Tags: asp.net, filesystems, file-permissions, windows-server-2003

I have an ASP.NET website which is using a filestream to read in a PDF image from a UNC share on a remote server 2003 box.

i attempt to load the file on the site (which simply embeds a PDF viewer on the site) but when i debug the code, it's throwing a security exception when i attempt to access the file.

> access to _________ path is denied.

So I granted access to the UNC path directory to the ASPNET user.
I also granted access to the user that's specified for anonymous access in the site itself in IIS. That did not work.

However, I when grant "everybody" access and the file comes through.

So, I need to know WHO is trying to access the file. the assumption is either the ASPNET user or the anonymous user setup in IIS. neither of which is gaining access.

I tried to set up file auditing on the Server 2003 box but it's not logging a failure in the security event log when I get an access denied exception.

Comment: I realized the issue I was having.

Comment: For some reason it was the NETWORK SERVICE that was trying to access the file rather than ASPNET or IUSR.
I granted read access to the NETWORK SERVICE to that directory and all is well.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` will get you the current user name, you could output this user to the screen or to a log file to check who it is.

The ASPNET user is the windows account that ASP.NET runs under, this is probably not the user who will be accessing the file.  You may need to explicitly grant privileges to the anonymous user to access the network (IUSR_MACHINENAME perhaps).

EDIT:

As you have enabled anonymous access in IIS, you can force your app to use anonymous access by modifying your web.config to use Forms authentication.  Search for '

```
<authentication mode="Forms" />
```

or

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
</authentication>
```

Comment: Ah, ok, so I logged that and found that it was simply the NT user who's accessing the site from their workstation.
How do I force anonymous access when accessing a file. 
I've attempted programmatic windows impersonation but can't seem to get that work right.

For example, in IIS, the site is enabled to use anonymous access with a given user "IUSR_KTSRV1".
How do I force this file streaming process to run under that user instead?

Comment: modify your web.config to use Forms authentication <authentication mode="Forms">

Comment: That's actually already set...:

  <authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="~/Home/Index" timeout="2880"/>
  </authentication>

Comment: Try unchecking Integrated Windows authentication on the Authentication Methods dialog in IIS.  If that doesn't work I'm afraid I'm running out of ideas :(

Comment: Oh also, make sure you are configuring the web app and not the web site, as settings on the web site would be overridden by settings on the web app

Comment: No worries if you're running out of ideas, haha.
But yeah, none of the Authenticated Access checkboxes are checked on the server.
When I log the WindowsIdentity it comes up with my domain\myusername. But when I've logged into the site those are not the credentials i used to log in.
This obviously works if I grant privileges of the file to "everyone". But not when I grant privileges to my IUSR anonymous account or the ASPNET account.

Answer (score 0):

I realized the issue I was having.
For some reason it was the NETWORK SERVICE that was trying to access the file rather than ASPNET or IUSR.
I granted read access to the NETWORK SERVICE to that directory and all is well.
Thanks again.